# TestNG - Cannot add a list of String as data provider

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm trying to pass a list of string as a DataProvider, here is my code:

```
    @DataProvider(name="test-urls")
    public Object[] testUrls(){
        ArrayList<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
        // do something here to add elements
        // i.e: data.add("test string 1");
        return new Object[] {data};     
    }
```

Here is the test:

```
    @Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = "test-urls")
    public void test(String url) {
        System.out.println("url: " + url);
    }
```

It looks like the simple test fails. Can you please show me what is wrong with my code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `Object[][]` or `Object[]` or `Iterator<Object[]` as per [this](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1139)

plus, in your case,  receive with the same `type` as `ArrayList<string>`

```
@DataProvider(name="test-urls")
    public Object[][] testUrls(){
        ArrayList<string> data = new ArrayList<>();
        // do something here to add elements
        // i.e: data.add("test string 1");
        return new Object[][] {data};     
    }

 @Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = "test-urls")
    public void test( ArrayList<string> list) {
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

Comment: are there any reasons why i need to return the 2D array? as i just want to use each of the element for each individual test case. Thanks

Comment: Object[X][Y]: every X is a single test invocation and Y its particular argument payload.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like an old-school DP style, it's worth to try a TestNG extension named [test-data-supplier](https://github.com/sskorol/test-data-supplier), which is an entity-driven DP. Then your sample will become as simple as:

```java
@DataSupplier(name="test-urls")
public List<String> testUrls(){
    return Arrays.asList("url1", "url2", "url3");
}
```

```java
@Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = "test-urls")
public void test(String url) {
    System.out.println("url: " + url);
}
```